# Xamarin image not showing in TabbedPage

Tags: image, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, tabbedpage

I have an image of the name logout.png that I try to display in a Tabbedpage. But it shows me a big grey circle. And when I put it on another page, it appears without problem

```
    <NavigationPage Title="{Static properties:Resources.LabelLogout}" Icon="logout.png">
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:LogoutPage/>

        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
```

[image]

Comment: not all images are appropriate for use as icons in tabs and titles - you need to refer to the platform docs for relevant restrictions

Comment: I don’t see any restriction on a logout.png. Thus the image is even a little smaller than the other images that are in the Tabbedpage

Comment: Check if logout.png is in specific platform resources. For example Android->Resources->drawable

Comment: Yes my image is in the Android->Resources->drawable folders since when I put it in a stacklayout on a page it appears. It’s just in the Tabbedpage that it doesn’t appear

Comment: I modified my post by adding the image in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `IconImageSource="logout.png"` to set Icon for Tabbar , not `Icon="logout.png"` . Have a look at follow sample code :

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabbedPageWithNavigationPage;assembly=TabbedPageWithNavigationPage"
            x:Class="TabbedPageWithNavigationPage.MainPage">
    <local:TodayPage />
    <NavigationPage Title="Schedule" IconImageSource="schedule.png">
        <x:Arguments>
            <local:SchedulePage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

[image]

Here is an [official sample project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/navigation-tabbedpagewithnavigationpage/) for reference .

Comment: I still have the same problem

Comment: @dna Okey , if possible you can share a sample project link here , I will check that .By the way , whether my shared sample project works .

Comment: Unfortunately I can’t share the project. I do not know if the image in question is not reserved for something else and therefore it does not appear

Comment: @dna No , you not need to share your current project . You can re-create a sample tabbed page project . If can reproduce this issue , you can share this sample project link here .